# Why is my git filter not getting invoked?

Tags: git, git-filter

I'm in a new git repo at ~/repositories/foo.  My .gitattributes looks like this:

```
*.txt   mycrypt
```

My .git/config looks like this:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    ignorecase = true
    precomposeunicode = true
[filter "mycrypt"]
    clean = tee /Users/matthew/temp/mycrypt.before.txt | openssl enc -base64 -pass pass:secret | tee /Users/matthew/temp/mycrypt.after.txt
```

I do the following, but my filter never gets invoked (when I list directory ~/temp, I don't see any mycrypt.* files.).  Why?

```
mkdir ~/temp # just for good measure
echo goo > goo.txt
git add goo.txt
git commit -m 'goo'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first thing you're missing is to apply the filter. In `.gitattributes`, instead of:

```
*.txt   mycrypt
```

you want:

```
*.txt   filter=mycrypt
```